# Dynamic embed URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm buildin a webserver for an embedded system.
The main page must embed another html file, whose address in created with javascript.

the javascript is the following

```
 <body class="mainPage" onload="getTerminalUrl()"> <br>
   <script>
      function getTerminalUrl() {
        var terminalUrl = "embedded.html"
        document.getElementById("embeddedTerm").setAttribute("src", terminalUrl); 
        document.getElementById("linkedTerm").setAttribute("action", terminalUrl); 
    }
    </script>
```

and it creates a link to embedded.html (just for this example), in two spots

a button:

```
<form id="linkedTerm" action="">
```

and an embedded form

```
<embed id="embeddedTerm" src="" style="width: 100%;">
```

The embedded page is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">

<h1>Heading</h1>

<p>paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

What happens is that, by using Firefox, i get the expected result

[image: Firefox]

With Chrome i get the embedded page only when i open the inspector or resize the window
[image: Chrome]

Do i Have to force a redraw or something to have the embedded page displayed consistently?
If instead of the Javascript i hardcode the URL everything works.

Thanks,

Marco

Comment: Why are you using `embed`, and not an `iframe`?

Comment: Have you tried `.src = terminalUrl`, instead of `setAttribute`?

Comment: also `window.addEventListener("load",getTerminalUrl)`

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your suggestion, with the iframe tag it's loaded correctly.
another thing that worked was forcing a refresh with:

var element = document.getElementById("embeddedTerm");
element.style.display = 'none';
element.style.display = 'block';

If you put this as answer, i will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe posted the correct answer.

using iframe

```
<iframe id="embeddedTerm" src="" style="width: 100%;">
```

as well as forcing a refresh with

```
var element = document.getElementById("embeddedTerm");
element.style.display = 'none'; 
element.style.display = 'block';
```

Thanks a lot